# How can I increase OpenCV realtime detector app's fps?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have face detector app which is using java's native cpp lines and OpenCV. It is detecting faces and drawing a circle around them.
But its fps is very low because of its working plan.

So I tried changing JavaCameraView's layout width and height to decrease resolution and increase fps but it was still has same fps. Then I tried adding setting resolution and fps [lines](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) to my cpp file but they didn't work.

Here's my changed cpp codes:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
void detect(Mat &input);
void JNICALL
Java_com_example_nativeopencvandroidtemplate_MainActivity_adaptiveThresholdFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                                                   jlong matAddr) {

    Mat &input = *(Mat *) matAddr;
    detect(input);
}
void detect(Mat &input) {
    String face_cascade_name = "/storage/emulated/0/ony.xml";
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    

    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor( input, frame_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY );
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
        Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width * 0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height * 0.5);
        ellipse(input, center, Size(faces[i].width * 0.5, faces[i].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8,
                0);
    }
}
}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template) its original template which I changed its cpp file to detecting faces.

And when I tried to add three classifiers and their lines for detecting another things and drawing another circles, app is stopping repeatedly on my Android OS. [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244806/how-can-i-solve-android-apps-stopping-by-low-fps) is my another problem about this project.

Comment: @Alex Cohn can you look at?

Comment: @isaaaaame can you look at?

Comment: @vSomers can you look at

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incomplete, but it looks like you create the classifier on each frame. That is not efficient.

Comment: So what I have to add? Thank you

Comment: @K22: Without seeing the exact code, it's hard to be sure, but it's possible you only need a `static` before `CascadeClassifier face_cascade`. I don't see how `face_cascade_name` is used though.